# Could not find method compile() for arguments in the module

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

The structure of my project looks like this https://zapodaj.net/d96c686a2cabe.png.html. There are 4 `build.gradle` files. One generally in the project and one for each module.
The main build.gradle file looks like this `REST-Web-Service -> build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

def javaProjects = subprojects.findAll {
    it.name == "common" & it.name == "core" && it.name == "web"
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

idea {
    project {
        jdkName = "1.8"
        languageLevel = "1.8"
        vcs = "Git"
    }
}

configure(javaProjects) {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    dependencies {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, the `build.gradle` file in the `common` module looks like this `REST-Web-Service -> common -> build.gradle`

```
group = 'com.common'


dependencies {

    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-validator")
    compile("com.google.guava:guava")
    compile group: 'commons-validator', name: 'commons-validator', version: '1.6'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.6'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.8.0'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.8.0'
}
```

When building a project with the Gradle tool, I get an error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Jonatan\Documents\GitHub\REST-Web-Services\common\build.gradle' line: 6

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':common'.
> Could not find method api() for arguments [com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
Could not find method api() for arguments [com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Comment: So could not find _compile_ or _api_?

Comment: Yes. Cannot be found.

Comment: Ok, but it cannot _api_ or _compile_? You have used _api_ nowhere as opposed to _compile_.

Comment: I added a plugin in module common: `java-library` and I changed `compile` to `api`. When you build the project again, an error pops up https://pastebin.com/Um6SZYhM Now there is a problem with compiling the project.

Comment: I forgot to provide the build.gradle file code in the core module. https://pastebin.com/YWCe01JG